# Background of HoverTool

Tags: python, html, css, background, bokeh

The example I'm using comes from the Bokeh documentation page, [Configuring Plot Tools](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html).

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
            desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
            imgs = [
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
            ],
            fonts=['<i>italics</i>',
                   '<pre>pre</pre>',
                   '<b>bold</b>',
                   '<small>small</small>',
                   '<del>del</del>'
                   ]
        )
    )

hover = HoverTool(
        tooltips="""
        <div>
            <div>
                <img
                    src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                    style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                    border="2"
                ></img>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
                <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
                <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        """
    )

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover],
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```

Given this code, how do I make the background of the HoverTool a specific color, right now I can only adjust the colors of the images and text separately.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes thank you, that was very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a quick search I found the way to override the `.bk-tooltip` style from the tooltip itself.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_file("toolbar.html")
source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
            desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
            imgs = [
               'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
               'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
               'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
               'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
               'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
            ],
            fonts=['<i>italics</i>',
                   '<pre>pre</pre>',
                   '<b>bold</b>',
                   '<small>small</small>',
                   '<del>del</del>'
                   ]
        )
    )

hover = HoverTool(
        tooltips="""
        <HTML>
        <HEAD>
        <style>
        .bk-tooltip {
            background-color: red !important;
            }
        </style>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
        <div>
            <div>
                <img
                    src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                    style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                    border="2"
                ></img>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
                <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
                <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </BODY>
        </HTML>
        """
    )

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover],
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```